# Which is better, [Table Exists Check + Select] or [Select + Error Handling]?

Tags: sql, sqlite

There exists several tables in an SQLite database. It is possible for data to be requested (from client) from a table which does not exist. If the table does exist, then desired data from table is sent as an *array of rows*, and if table does not exist, an *empty array* is to be returned.

There are 2 ways (i can think of):

- Table Exists Check + Select
- Select + Error Handling

Which way would be better (or faster)?

Comment: The best solution would be one where you have a proper schema where all table names are static and no tables are ever created, altered or dropped during normal operation, so a select on a non-existing table should never happen.

Comment: In performance terms, 2º solution might be better because you only select once.

Comment: @Philipp thats fast, but tables in this `db` are in the form `date_DD_MM_YYYY` and are constantly created upon `INSERT` and dropped upon `DELETE`.

Comment: @wolfram77 You should replace these with a single table with an additional date-field which is part of the primary key.

Comment: the sqlite database will be inserted with around 10k rows per day, and on every insert a cross-check needs to be performed if a similar record already exists. such a cross-check is only performed within the day. the software runs on raspberry pi.

Comment: in such a case, would it be better to merge is to a single table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of depends on what your default case is. If the table will exist in most of the cases use the second option. As @CristianAbelleira pointed out in the comments, this will also reduce load on the database because it's one less transaction.

If on the other hand you expect the table to not exist most of the time, implement some kind of check before the actual select. This can be done via your first option but I also like the idea from Daves answer.

Comment: in most cases tables would exist in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I would run with the third idea.

When you connect to the dB get a quick list of the table names (works as a good double check that the connection is working OK) store these in a list somewhere, then as the user creates their query give them a drop down list with these table names in it (or somehow double check the entered name is in that list).

Only downside here is if the user creates a new table during the session.

Otherwise, if the user is doing a free form SQL statement just let the server throw our the error and then deal with it with a sensible error message.

The dB engine is likely more efficient at this than your 'check table exists' code. Unless of course you are generating a request building graphic, in which case the above scenario will probably work best (provided you don't have hundreds of tables).

Dave.

Comment: even though tables will be created slowly while running, lots of tables can be dropped at a time. however, the idea of table name cache is great.

Comment: @wolfram77 from reading one of your other comments, your problem will be maintaining an up to date cache if they are rapidly created on inserts. If this is the case temp tables may be a good option (does sqlite support them?) As they would be dropped when the connection closes.

Comment: inserts should be at max 10/s. have not heard of temp tables before, but data should not be lost if connection is lost. currently using select with error handling, as suggested by Cristian & Andre.